# asp.net core bootstrap two column using post

Tags: css, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have a very simple form I am using for test/learning.
I let VS create it using Scaffold New Razor Page.

I then modified it trying to get two columns for the create page.
I have tried lots of stuff but with no luck.
The latest is with CSS and Flexbox.

What in the world am I missing?
The below works, meaning it submits and updates the database but everything is still in one column.

```
    style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .row {
        display: flex;
    }

    /* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
    .column {
        flex: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
    }
</style>

<h2>Create</h2>

<div class="row">
    <form method="post">
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
            <h2>Column 1</h2>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RebateDetail.RebateProgramId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="RebateDetail.RebateProgramId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RebateProgramId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RebateDetail.RetailerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="RebateDetail.RetailerId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RetailerId"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
            <h2>Column 2</h2>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RebateDetail.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="RebateDetail.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="RebateDetail.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RebateDetail.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="RebateDetail.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="RebateDetail.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Simple" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
I moved the Form up and also realized I was not using BS4.
This works while I am now going and working through some tutorials as upgrading to BS4.

```
 /* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
    .inputColumns {
        flex: 50%;
        padding: 70px;
        background-color:bisque;
          }
</style>

<h2>Create</h2>
<form method="post">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="inputColumns" style="background-color:darkgray;">
            <h2>Rebate Details</h2>
            <p>This section is for the rebate amounts and info</p>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RebateDetail.RebateProgramId"> Rebate Program ID</label>
                <select asp-for="RebateDetail.RebateProgramId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RebateProgramId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RebateDetail.RetailerId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="RebateDetail.RetailerId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RetailerId"></select>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the column style? it should be `col` or `col-<modifier>` (sm, md, lg) or you can `col-<modifier>-<number>` e.g. `col-md-4`, the max the number can be is 12

Keep in mind that `asp.net core` templates at present doesn't reference `bootstrap 4`.  You will have to manually update the styling to reference `bootstrap 4`.

your case you might want something like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
     <!--- column 1 ---->
     <div class="form-group">
     </div>
  </div
  <div class="col-6">
     <!--- column 2 ---->
      <div class="form-group">
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

what you are doing is not helping with the extra selectors assuming you have the files referenced correctly for bootstrap to function.  You using something is already written not re-writing the wheel.

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: First off, your comment about the version of bootstrap caught my mistake one, I assumed core 2.1 was BS4.  Secondly, moving my Form above row fixed it.  I will update with what worked.